# Force a HtmlButton to lose focus

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom

I have a VueJS app where a HTML button is on the screen and when it's clicked it's appropriate to have "focus" but I'd like the option to remove the focus after a short delay.

```
if (props.defocus === "true" || props.defocus === true) {
  // de-focus the button after 400ms
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (el.value !== null) {
      el.value.blur();
    }
   }, 400);
}
```

Now I did mention that this is a VueJS project but really this is just DOM API and JS/TS. I use setTimeout to wait 400ms and I am able to call the `blur()` function on the button. However, this does *not* appear to do anything. Now I guess this could be two things:

1. I have successfully removed the focus on the button element according to the DOM but somehow VueJS is not picking this up and reacting to it (aka, the focus styling remains)
2. The call to `focus()` is somehow silently ignored (there are no errors)

Is there a way to inspect the focus state in developer tools? Is there something I'm missing in getting the behavior I'm looking for?

[image: illustration of component]

Just for the visual minded in the group, the component above is where when I click on a button and make it selected the focus state is represented by a purple outline. I want that to go away after a user has clicked it.

Comment: Did you try to set it to watcher for 'props.defocus'

Comment: No but there should be no need. I trigger off the click event on the button, delay 400ms and then call blur(). The function IS called it just doesn't produce the behavior I'm looking for.

Comment: what is `el`??? what is `el.value`? We need more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to use the pointer to the button didn't work but instead I found that simply querying for the focus element gives me a handler where I can call blur and have it work:

```
if (props.defocus === "true" || props.defocus === true) {
  // de-focus the button after delay
  setTimeout(() => {
    // QUERY FOR FOCUS ELEMENT
    const e2 = document.querySelector(":focus");
    if (e2 && (e2 as HTMLButtonElement).blur) {
      (e2 as HTMLButtonElement).blur();
    }
  }, Number(props.defocusDelay));
}
```

This works without issue and unless someone else has a better solution I will mark this as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Make a directive file Defocus.ts;

```
export default {
    name: 'defocus',
    priority: 700,
    bind(el: any, binding: any) {
        el._onClick = () => {
            setTimeout(()=> {
                el.blur();
            }, 400)
        }
        el.addEventListener('click', el._onClick);
    },

    unbind(el: any) {
        el.removeEventListener('click', el._onClick);
    }
};
```

Then you import and use

```
import Defocus from "@/shared/directives/Defocus";
@Component ({
    directives: {
        Defocus 
    }
})
```

Then in template:

```
<button v-defocus>Click Me</button>
```